# don't show images from ImageField in django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-media

Django doesn't show images from ImageField in a template.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    emp_email = models.EmailField()
    emp_contact = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    emp_role = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    emp_salary = models.IntegerField()
    venue_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name
```

template:

```
<tbody>

    {% for emp in employees %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ emp.emp_name }}</th>
            <td>{{ emp.emp_email }}</td>
            <td>{{ emp.emp_contact }}</td>
            <td>{{ emp.emp_role }}</td>
            <td>{{ emp.emp_salary}}</td>
            <td>
                <a style="margin-right: 30px;" href="{% url 'edit-employee' emp.id %}">EDITAR</a>
                <a href="{% url 'delete-employee' emp.id %}">ELIMINAR</a>
            </td>
            <td>
             {%if venue.venue_image%}
             {{venue.venue_image.url}}
             {%endif%}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

views.py
[image]

I'm expecting the image here:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures. Post your views as text.

Comment: `{{venue.venue_image.url}}` - this will give an URL only, not `<img>` tag. You must write `<img src="...` by yourself. Also `venue` is never initialized thus it cannot return any images or whatever field value. Your iterator variable is `emp`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your if condition in your template. You are getting your employees data with for loop and using variable emp not venue. Use this if condition and your image url will be displayed

```
{% if emp.venue_image %}
    {{emp.venue_image.url}}
{% endif %}
```

If you want to display the image you need to use image tag like this

```
{% if emp.venue_image %}
    <img src="{{emp.venue_image.url}}">
{% endif %}
```